# Is there a function to Check if date is real in VBA ( including leapyears )

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to test a user input ( string ) if it's a real date. So date 29 feb 2015 is false but 29 feb 2016 is true. If there isn't a function how what would Be the best wat to test IT?

Comment: The function you are looking for is `ISDATE()`

Comment: We've learned that isdate() only checks the input format and if it's datetime or can Be converted to a datetime but IT doesn't Check if the date is "real" , i could Be Wrong that would make my work a whole lot easyer

Comment: in the immediate window type `? IsDate("29 feb 2015")`  it will return False then try `? IsDate("29 feb 2016")` It will return true.

Comment: Great much thx , if you post you awnser i can Award it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is

```
ISDATE()
```

in the immediate window type

```
? IsDate("29 feb 2015")
```

It will return False. Then try:

```
? IsDate("29 feb 2016")
```

It will return true.